# Проблемы с вывод при компиляцией под х86

Tags: c++

Есть простая функция которая возводит число в куб.

```
double refcube(double &x)
{
    x *= x * x;
    return x;
}
```

К примеру `double x = 3.0`, то на экран мне выведет `27 = 3`

```
std::cout << refcube(x)<< " = " << x << std::endl;
```

Если я изменю вывод сделав его таким

```
std::cout << refcube(x); 
std::cout << " = " << x << std::endl;
```

то выведет измененное значение переменной `x`, то есть `27 = 27`.

При компиляции под x64 такой проблемы нет.

С чем это может быть связано?

P.S система x64

Comment: Сдается мне, что у вас тут неопределенное поведение, ибо вы надаетесь, что побочный  эффект от изменения переменной `x` будет применен к ней до того, как вы ее выведете.

Comment: А может это зависть от разрядности системы?

Comment: Вполне. А еще сегодня лунное затмение.

Comment: Ну я думаю затмение вряд ли влияет))

Comment: @VTT: Даже до C++17 неопределенного поведения тут нет, ибо модификация `x` надежно изолирована от внешнего мира точками следования на входе в функцию и на выходе из нее. До С++17 поведение неспецифицированно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это может быть связано с версией вашего компилятора и поддерживаемого им стандарта языка.

Начиная со стандарта С++17 языка С++ левая часть оператора `<<` целиком и полностью вычисляется до правой части. Этот код

```
std::cout << refcube(x) << " = " << x << std::endl;
```

должен выводить `27 = 27`.

В более ранних версиях языка выводится может и `27 = 3` и `27 = 27`. Поведение не специфицировано.

Как только вы разбиваете это выражение на два отдельных выражения, неоднозначность исчезает во всех версиях спецификации. Вывод должен быть `27 = 27`.

Comment: Добавлю, что пруфы можно найти тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38501596/2752075

Answer (score -2):

```
double refcube(double &x)
{
    x *= x * x;
    return x;
}
```

Измените на:

```
double refcube(double x)
{
    x *= x * x;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы функция изменила значение переменной. Я просто пытаюсь понять почему при компиляции под х86 выводится на экран еще не измененное значение, если я не разобью вывод на два отдельных оператора.